# How to add a link that can load to file upload button upon clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code. Which ask user to upload the file.

```css
.form-control {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:  "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue;
}

.form-horizontal {
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 130px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:  "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://gregpike.net/demos/bootstrap-file-input/bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>


<body>
   
    <!--- DISPLAY THE FORM -->
    

<form  id="id-method1Form" class="form-horizontal" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='JdUjVaRwOkOxbQmoeSaSHTaDNTlwjs5U' />    <div id="div_id_inputfile_param" class="form-group"> <label for="id_inputfile_param" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Input File</label> <div class="controls col-lg-8">
  
  <input class="clearablefileinput" id="id_inputfile_param" name="inputfile_param" data-filename-placement="inside" type="file" /> </div> </div> 


                </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="aab controls col-lg-2"></div> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <input type="submit"
    name="submit"
    value="Submit"
    
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="submit-id-submit"
    
    
    /> </div> </div> </form>

    <!--- Style the Browse button-->

        <script>$(document).ready(function(){$('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();});</script>

</body>


</html>
```

What I want to do then is to add a link next to the browse button.
Something like this:

[image]

So when it's clicked the default file will be loaded to input file field.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean with the default file?

Comment: An `<input type="file" />` value is just the path of the file. Try to give the default path of the file. I don't realy know the purpose of this, but it can be different from a computer to another...

Comment: @JeroenBellemans: the default file is the test file linked by `this file` in my last example above. So let's say my default file is `foo.png`. Using my code, if `this_file` is clicked, then the `Browse` button will change to `foo.png` button.

Comment: I don't know if this could work, but if the `href-attribute` is the link to the default file, you could try to add the content of the `href-attribute` to the `value` of the input.

Comment: There's no path property on `File` object, even for the files added from local File System through the pop-up. If you want to use a default file, send some additional parameter in your Form POST request indicating that the user opted for default file instead of his own file. You cannot set the path value for any file inputs